# como eu posso imprimir uma única linha de uma tabela mysql usando python

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados

#cada linha da tabela tem um ID(um numero especifico)quero que o usuario digite o id referente a linha e somente essa linha seja impressa

```
print('\n Visualizar somente um item especifico')
            cod = int(input('Digite o Codigo do carro: '))
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 
loja_de_carrosv1.esportivos WHERE id = 'cod'")
            resultado = cursor.fetchall()
            print(resultado)
            print('\n')
# o codigo q eu tenho so esta retornando " [] " quando digitado o id da linha
```

Comment: `id = 'cod'`, você está selecionando os registros que o `id` é igual a `'cod'`. Pesquise sobre como injetar parâmetros na sua consulta para utilizar a variável `cod`, que acredito que é o que deseja fazer.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!!!!

Comment: o comando ficou assim:     cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM loja_de_carrosv1.esportivos WHERE id = %d" % cod)

Answer (score -3):

Tente desta forma se estiver usando o pymysql.

Reescrevi seu código aqui pra adaptar a minha base de teste e deu certo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNlQa.png

```
import pymysql

def conn():
    return pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='user', passwd='senha@?', db='basededados')

print('\n Visualizar somente um item especifico')
cod = int(input('Digite o Codigo do carro: '))
print('Codigo selecionado: ', cod)
sql = "SELECT * FROM HISTORY WHERE chat_id = %s"
val = (cod,)
currsor = conn().cursor()
currsor.execute(sql, val)   
result = currsor.fetchall()
for x in result:
    print(x)
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: por exemplo: eu tenho uma tabela com 2 carros, (id = 1, nome = carro azul) (id=2, nome = carro vermelho). eu ja consigo imprimir na tela a tabela inteira com os 2 carros porem em um determinado momento o usuario pode escolher se quiser, imprimir somente 1 carro da tela digitando o id do carro assim imprimindo somente a linha referente ao carro selecionado. criei  a variavel 'cod ' so pra armazenar oq sera digitado porem nao esta impriminto nada na tela